# rxJS and ngrx - what is the right structure of success / fail inside an effect?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I work in angular 2 Project and use ngrx and rxjs technologies.

Now I have a problem:

I try to declare an Effect. 
The effect has http request, and **only when it success** I want to call other http-request, and so **only if it also success** - then dispatch an success-action.

I has tested it by throw an error but it always dispatch the action!

See:

```
       @Effect()
createEntity$ = this.actions$.ofType(CREATE_ENTITY)
    .switchMap((action: CreateEntity) => {

        return this.httpService.getDefaultEntityData(action.payload.type).map((entity) => {
            return  Observable.throw("testing only");
            /*if (entity) {
                 entity.title = entity.type;
                 return this.httpService.addEntity(entity);
            }*/
        })

            .catch((error) => Observable.of(new createEntityFailure(error)))
            .map(mappedResponse => ({ type: CREATE_ENTITY_SUCCESS, payload: mappedResponse }))
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
this.actions$
    .ofType(CREATE_ENTITY)
    .map((action: CreateEntity) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(payload =>
      this.httpService.getDefaultEntityData(payload.type)
        .mergeMap(entity => this.httpService.addEntity(entity))
        // .mergeMap(entity => Observable.throw('error')) // or this for testing
        .mergeMap(response => new actions.Action(...))
        .catch(error => new actions.Error(...))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either split this up into multiple actions or just add another API call in the same effect using `Observable.forkJoin`

```
       @Effect() createEntity$ = this.actions$.ofType(CREATE_ENTITY)
.switchMap((action: CreateEntity) => {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
       this.httpService.callOne(),
       this.httpService.callTwo()
    )
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(new createEntityFailure(error)))
    .map(mappedResponse => ({ type: CREATE_ENTITY_SUCCESS, payload: mappedResponse }))
});
```

As forkJoin is parallel that won't work for you. You can just switchMap on the first API call and return the second:

```
       @Effect() createEntity$ = this.actions$.ofType(CREATE_ENTITY)
.switchMap((action: CreateEntity) => {
    return this.httpService.callOne();
 })
 .switchMap((response) => {
    return this.httpService.callTwo()
      .map(secondResponse => ({ 
          type: CREATE_ENTITY_SUCCESS,
          payload: {
              first: response, 
              second: secondResponse
          } 
       }))
 })
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(new createEntityFailure(error)))
});
```

Comment: @user2783091 edited the response to include a different option

Answer (score 1):

1) If you returning `Observable` you probably want `swithMap` instead of `map`

2) Action always has been dispatched because you return non error `Observable` from `catch`. Changing `Observable.of` to `Observable.throw` will throw error further

```
@Effect()
createEntity$ = this.actions$.ofType(CREATE_ENTITY)
    .switchMap((action: CreateEntity) =>
        this.httpService.getDefaultEntityData(action.payload.type)
    )
    .switchMap((entity) => { //                                     <------ switchMap here
        return  Observable.throw("testing only");
        /*if (entity) {
             entity.title = entity.type;
             return this.httpService.addEntity(entity);
        }*/
    })
    .catch((error) =>
        Observable.throw(new createEntityFailure(error)) //         <------ throw here
    )
    .map((mappedResponse) => 
        ({ type: CREATE_ENTITY_SUCCESS, payload: mappedResponse })
    );
```