# How to close MatDialogBox or any div when API is successful in NGXS state?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngxs

I have started learning state management using NGXS. So far everything is fine but have few questions regarding some scenarios like -

1. If a Mat Dialog box is open (or any div - here I've both the scenarios in my project) and from inside it an API is called, how can I close the dialog only if API returns success?
2. Suppose a user logs out, how can I reset the states to default values?

For the first case below is my code for the state, action & dispatcher:

**abc.action.ts**

```
export class AddExamCategory {
    static readonly type = '[ExamCategory] Add';
    constructor(public payload: ExamCategory) {}
}
```

**abc.state.ts**

```
export interface ExamCategoryStateModel {
    examCategoryList: ExamCategory[];
}

@State<ExamCategoryStateModel>({
    name: 'examCategory',
    defaults: {
        examCategoryList: []
    }
})

@Injectable()
export class ExamCategoryState {

    constructor(private _adminService: AdminService) {}

    @Action(AddExamCategory)
    addExamCategory({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<ExamCategoryStateModel>, { payload }: AddExamCategory) {
        return this._adminService.createExamCategory(payload).pipe(tap(response => {
            patchState({ examCategoryList: [] }); // Want to close the modal/div after this part. If API returns ERROR do not close.
        }));
    }
}
```

**abc.component.ts**

```
this.store.dispatch(new AddAdminUser({ ...this.adminRegistrationForm.value, password: this.password.value }))
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.store.dispatch(new GetAdminUsers());
      this.dialogRef.close(true)
    });
```

Currently it's like this but it closes no matter what's the status of API.

For the second case, in the service where I have written the logic for `logout()` I have written like this: `this.store.reset({})`. Though it's resetting the state but not with the default values in it. I have multiple states to reset on this single logout method.

How to work on these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra property on your state to track the requesting state of your application ('requesting','idle') [you can create extra states as needed to track 'success' and 'error' response from the server]

when dispatch `GetAdminUsers` set the value of the newely added state to `requesting` and at `GetAdminUsersComplete` set the value to `idle`

subscribe to a selector that's read the state on your `ngOnInit` and call `dialogRef.clse(true)` inside of it. like following:

```
this.store
      .pipe(
        select(selectors.selectRequestState),
        skip(1) //only start tracking after request created
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result == 'idle')
          this.dialogRef.close()
      });
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ofc3q?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Reset State**

I don't think there is a simple way to reset the state with the store. You need to move through all your state features and implement `reset` action that set the state to initial state.

the simplest solution is to refresh the browser page after user logout using  `location.reload();`

- if you keep the store inside localstorage you need to remove it first then do the reload

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ofc3q?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to accomplish that is with an effect, after you dispatch your action you should be able to trigger other action like "UsserAddedSuccessfully" and read it after that close that modal.

read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193334/rxjs-and-ngrx-what-is-the-right-structure-of-success-fail-inside-an-effect) for more detail.